# Usage of accumulate with a custom object

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

I am using opencv library with C++, and I am trying to compute sum of points which are contained in `vector<Point2f> difference`

Point class has x property which is `float`.

```
float pointSumX(Point2f pt1,Point2f pt2)
{
    return (pt1.x + pt2.x);
}
```

I defined function as above, and call it from accumulate shown below. But it throws error.

```
float avgMotionX = accumulate(difference.begin(),difference.end(),0,pointSumX);
```

Error is:

> error: could not convert ‘__init’ from ‘int’ to ‘cv::Point_’  __init = __binary_op(__init, *__first);

Note: I am using C++11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
float pointSumX(Point2f pt1, Point2f pt2)
```

should be

```
float pointSumX(float lhs, const Point2f& rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs.x;
}
```

as `lhs` is the accumulator.

Note also that you should call it

```
std::accumulate(difference.begin(), difference.end(), 0.f, pointSumX); // 0.f instead of 0
```

to return `float` and not `int`.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. What's the reason for const and & in the function?

Comment: @Bhoke: To avoid copies: pass by const reference instead of by value. (For `Point2f`, it can be debatable as the class is small, but by default pass object by const reference instead of by value).